# Looping through arrays, up and left direction work, down and right direction returning error?

Tags: c++, arrays

Sorry this question isn't worded very well, i'm not exactly sure how to ask it.

This statement works correctly

```
if (direction == 'w' || direction == 'W')
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] == playerTile)
            {
                if (board[i-1][j] == ' ')
                {
                    board[i - 1][j] = playerTile;
                    board[i][j] = ' ';
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "Invalid Move" << std::endl;
                    _getch();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

while this one causes invalid error, and the player moves to the bottom of the board, I think it's a problem to do with the [i+1] section, as when its changed to [i - 1]; like the previous if statement it works

```
else if (direction == 's' || direction == 'S')
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] == playerTile)
            {
                if (board[i + 1][j] == ' ')
                {
                    board[i + 1][j] = playerTile;
                    board[i][j] = ' ';
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "Invalid Move" << std::endl;
                    _getch();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about it, what are expecting from board[i - 1][j] when i == 0 ? Same exercice with board[i + 1][j] when i rows-1 ?

Comment: Off topic: use `std::tolower` on `direction` and save yourself having to test `direction == 'S'` and it's upper-cased cronys.

Comment: `_getch` has the ego signature of Visual Studio. Visual Studio has an excellent debugger. Your productivity will improve dramatically if you learn to use it. Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/sc65sadd.aspx

Comment: because your arrays begin to 0, the number of rows is for example 4, then when the player moves to the number n, he actually goes to the number (n-1)

Comment: You may have a buffer overrun or out of range issue when accessing `board[i + 1]`.  When `i` is (`rows - 1`), you add 1 to this value producing the value of `rows`, which is probably out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Your safest solution is to test your array expressions before you use them:

```
if (i > 0)
{
  if (board[i-1][j] /*... */

and
if ((i + 1) < rows)
{
  if (board[i+1][j] /* ... */
```

This should demonstrate why you are seeing issues in your code.